# GWT 2.7 maven project integration with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I found good starter of GWT 2.7.0 application that work with maven.
Here is [repository](https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-example)

Unfortunatelly owner/creator don't use eclipse, so he can help me.

I would like to have this project to work with eclipse and to be well integrated (like official ant project- stockwatcher f.e.).

My problem is that I can't run this project in eclipse in super dev mode. The only options I have is:
[[image: options to run[2]]
f.e. I can run install witch will compile project.
But I don't have option to run in SuperDevMode

The second problem is that I can't add GWT sdk to app using right mouse button on project -> Properties as You can see here:
[image: see here]

I can run this project using maven in linux konsole, but I can't do this by clicking in eclipse.

Please help

---

EDIT

My project structure in eclipse after import from git repository:
[image]

Here is main pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.hpfsc</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>server</module>
        <module>shared</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <gwtVersion>2.7.0</gwtVersion>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <tomcat.webport>8082</tomcat.webport>
        <tomcat.ajpport>8182</tomcat.ajpport>
        <tomcat.context>/parent</tomcat.context>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>

        <defaultGoal>clean install  tomcat7:run-war-only</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>

                <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>  <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppProjectValidator</name>
                            <arguments>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
                            <arguments>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>${tomcat.context}</path>
                    <port>${tomcat.webport}</port>
                    <ajpPort>${tomcat.ajpport}</ajpPort>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <JAVA_OPTS>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</JAVA_OPTS>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is composed of 3 submodules. When importing the project into Eclipse, you should then have 4 projects in your workspace: `parent`, `shared`, `server` and `web`.

`parent` should be a simple project (this is why you don't have many options in `Run As…`), and `shared`, `server` and `web` should be Java projects.

The `web` project is where GWT client code is (in addition to `shared`), and the GPE should automatically configure it as a GWT project, with the GWT SDK taken from the Maven dependencies (so you won't have a GWT "library" –in Eclipse parlance– in your dependencies, only the JRE/JDK and a "Maven Dependencies" library).
This is also on that `web` project that you'll `Run As…` → `Web Application`.

Comment: Why my eclipse produce only three modules? It is because of bad maven configuration? Should I create new submodule named parent (like server f.e.)? Or should I edit main pom.xml to make it work. I also understand that I have to copy gwt sdk from main pom.xml to client pom.xml?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Eclipse so maybe I misremember and it won't create a project for the parent module; it's useless anyway as far as Eclipse is concerned. And no you shouldn't have to modify the POMs.

Comment: Why it is useless? What Ide do You propose and Why?

Comment: The `parent` module doesn't contain code, only "configuration"; it's of little use within Eclipse (apart from triggering "update project from Maven" or "Run As… → Maven"). I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA, but haven't done any real GWT dev since then.